# Display non-const string (error message) in Qt

Tags: c++11, qt5

Recently, I had to code some kind of input validation in a Qt GUI project.
During a failing validation process, I would like to inform the user what exactly went wrong. Hence, I created QMessageBoxes with a short summary and the detailed error message gained by std::exception::what().

Alas, QMessageBoxes get constant strings, but exception::what() returns a *non-constant* C-like string.

What is the best way to solve / circumvent this issue? I need a temporary conventional widget with the ability to display a runtime error message non-editable, but preferably copyable. Perhaps, QMessageBox is not the best candidate for doing this?

Due to exterior constraints, I am using Qt 5.7 with C++ 11 and without Qt Quick.

EDIT: For the sake of a future reader: This solution seems to work:

```
try{ // ...
}
catch (const out_of_range& e){
                QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Critical, "Knoten zu groß", QString::fromStdString(static_cast<const string&>("short info. error message:\n" + static_cast<string>(e.what()))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youcan use `const_cast` in order to cast an object to const and viceversa

[An example from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)